# Regarding a variable in C, is an assignment always equivalent to a definition of that variable?

Tags: c, compiler, variables, declarations

Is there a difference between defining a variable in C and assigning a value to a variable in C?

I know that declaring a variable simply means telling the name and its type like `int a`.

On the other hand defining a variable means telling the compiler its value.

So in my understanding there are the following associations between these concepts:

- Declaration - Name + Type (of an identifier)
- Declaration - Value (of an identifier)

Comment: Declaration of a variable is information for the compiler only.  Once the code is compiled, it isn't any sort of operation, so it doesn't "cost" anything.  Think of it like a compiler hint on how to interpret the bytes containing the value.

Comment: In C and C++, "declaration" and "definition" have very distinct meanings due to the way compilation works, and your definitions above are wrong. "Declaration" means telling the compiler that something exists. "Definition" means giving the compiler details: the body of functions, structs and classes, or a definite place to live for variables. A definition need not tell the compiler a variable's value.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer strictly regarding C, or also regarding C++ (which is rather different in this respect)? The question just mentions C, but the tags also include C++, so it's not clear whether you really want information on C++ or not.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I am interested in both specialized definitions for C/C++ and general concepts and definitions.

Comment: @JenniferAnderson: There is no "C/C++". And for this question in particular, C and C++ *radically* differ.

Answer (score 6):

## C++

Oddly enough, C++ is actually rather simpler than C (in at least some respects) when it comes to declarations vs. definitions, so let's start with it.

### Declaration

In C++, a variable declaration would look something like: `extern int a;`. This tells the compiler that there's an `int` named `a` that it should assume it'll be able to access.

The compiler can then produce code that uses `a`, but in the object code, references to `a` will have some sort of record that tells the linker that this is intended to refer to `a`, but doesn't define it. It's then up to the linker to find the actual definition of `a` and...link those other references to it. If it can't find a definition of `a`, you'll get an "undefined reference" error from the linker.

### Definition

Pretty much anything that doesn't include the `extern` on it is a definition. That is, something like `int a;` is a definition. This not only declares `a` (i.e., tells the compiler that `a` is a variable of type `int`) but also tells it to allocate space for `a` to be stored in. If, somewhere else in the program there's an `extern int a;` (and this definition of `a` allows it to be visible there) the linker will fix up that declaration to refer to this definition of `a`.

### Initialization

In C++, the difference between initialization and assignment is much more profound than it is in C. For example, references can only be initialized, not assigned. For example, let's consider code like this:

```
int a;   
int &ra = a;

ra = b;
```

In this case, `int a;` defines the variable `a`. The `int &ra = a;` defines `ra` to be a reference to an `int`, and initializes it with `a`, so `ra` refers to `a`.

The `ra = b;` is an assignment--but unlike the initialization, it doesn't actually assign to `ra` itself at all. Rather, since `ra` is a reference, it actually assigns to the variable to which `ra` refers (which is to say, `a`).

### Assignment

As noted above, the `ra = b;` line above is an assignment. Note that the `int &ra = a;` line includes an `=` sign, but it's still not an assignment. If it's part of a definition, like: `T a = b;`, the `=` signifies initialization, not assignment. You only get assignment when the `=` is separate.

```
int a = 1; // initialization

int a;
a = 1;     // assignment
```

This becomes especially important when/if you overload operators, because it affects what operator will be called in a given situation.

```
class foo { 
public:
    foo(int); // used for something like `foo f = 1;`
    foo &operator=(int); // used for things like `foo f; f = 1;
};
```

In some cases, you might have (for example) defined a constructor, but deleted the assignment operator, in which case initialization will be allowed, but assignment won't.

## C

By the time C was being standardized, there were a number of compilers that didn't all work quite the same way. Because of this, the C committee had to jump through some hoops to make a single set of rules that provided compatibility with most existing code.

### locals

Let's start with the simple normal case: for a variable inside of a function, you basically have three storage classes:

```
int foo() { 
    extern int a;
    static int b;
    int c; // `auto int c;` is equivalent
```

In this case, the `extern int a;` is a declaration, saying that somewhere at global scope, somebody has defined a variable named `a`, and we're declaring it here so the code in this function knows about it and can refer to it.

The `static int b;` defines a variable with local scope (its name is only visible in this functions) and static storage duration (it exists for the life of the program, rather than being re-created each time the function is executed).

The `int c;` of course defines a variable with local scope and `auto` storage duration, so it's destroyed every time you exit the scope, and created anew each time you enter the scope.

### Globals

Here's where things get really hairy. To maintain compatibility with existing code, the C committee defined a couple of concepts that were new and unique: tentative definitions and composite types. It also defines a term called "linkage", which is at least sort of like what most of us think of as `scope`--that is, the visibility of the name that allows the linker to link something else to this definition. As they defined the term, there are three forms of linkage: external (visible throughout the program), `internal` (visible only within a single translation unit) and `none` (only visible in the local scope).

Continuing with our theme of starting with the simplest case, we'll start with a definition that includes initialization, like: `int a = 1;`. This is a variable definition. It declares `a` to be a variable of type `int`, allocates storage for it, and initializes it with the value `1` (and it has no linkage).

From here things get a little hairy though. For example, consider code like:

```
int a;

int a = 1;
```

In C++ this would be prohibited as a violation of the one definition rule. In C, however, it's allowed. The first `int a;` is a *tentative* definition. If there were no other definition of `a`, it would define `a`, allocate storage, and (since it's a global) signify that `a` will be initialized to `0`.

Likewise, we could have:

```
static int a;

int a = 1;
```

A tentative definition can contain the `static` specifier, so this is still a tentative definition followed by a definition. The `static` from the tentative definition is included in the type, so overall we've defined a single variable named `a` with static storage duration and internal linkage that's initialized to `1`.

We could also have:

```
static int a;

extern int a;
```

Now, this might seem like a conflict. The `static` specifies internal linkage, while the `extern` seems to specify external linkage. In fact, it is allowed. In this case, the `extern int a;` basically acts like a declaration, creating a reference to the `static int a;`, so we have one definition of `a` as an `int` with internal linkage.

If, however, we try to change that around:

```
extern int a;

static int a;
```

The situation changes completely. A tentative definition can specify `static`, but it *can't* specify `extern`. As such, with this ordering, the `extern int a;` is a full definition of `a` that specifies that `a` has external linkage. The `static int a;` then attempts to specify that `a` has internal linkage, which creates a conflict, so the compiler will normally reject the code with an error message.

This isn't the only possible conflict either. For example:

```
static int a;

int a;
```

...also creates a conflict, so we'd expect the code to be rejected with an error message.

### Assignment vs. initialization

In C, there are no references, and no user-defined operator overloading, so the difference between initialization and assignment isn't important as often as it is in C++. There are a few cases, especially initialization of arrays, however, where we still need to keep track of the difference:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4}; // allowed--initializes `a`

int a[4];                // no problem, but `a` isn't initialized
a = { 1, 2, 3, 4};       // Error!
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a difference between defining a variable in C and assigning a value to a variable in C?

You can only define a variable once but you can assign a variable multiple times.

Conversely, defining a variable does not necessarily give it a value. e.g.

```
main()
{
 int a;
 printf("a has the value %d\n", a);
}
```

This will usually compile but is undefined behavior. You may get the value zero or you may bet some other value. Or it may crash.

Comment: In C parlance, the `int a;` is not a definition but a declaration.

Comment: @amon, unlike function definition, the term variable definition does not appear as such in the C standard.   However, "6.7 Declarations [5]  A definition
of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
— for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;".  A local variable does not have the linkage issues of globals; simply declaring a local reserves (automatic(stack)) storage, therefore it is also a definition, no?

Comment: @ErikEidt you're probably right, that makes sense for local variables. Thanks for finding that quote!

Comment: How would this crash? So long as space is actually allocated for `a`, the printf should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, it can do anything. Usually you'll just get junk, but the compiler could decide not to allocate space until first assignment.

Comment: Strictly speaking using an uninitialized variable is not undefined behavior. In this case the behavior is unpredictable (the value of a could be any value in the range of an int), but is defined - printf prints the value of a.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are statically strongly typed languages, which means you need to provide the compiler with explicit instructions about variables you are about to use in terms of:

- type
- size

C* compiler in turn will allocate memory for this variable for later assignment

Unlike Python for example, which is a dynamically typed language, it can infer datatype of a variable from the value you assign to it

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a difference between defining a variable in C and assigning a value to a variable in C?

Definitely, yes.

> I know that declaring a variable simply means telling the name and its type like int a.

... and allocating a chunk of *memory* that will eventually hold any value given to the [int] variable known to your application as "**a**".  To the rest of the computer, it's some arbitrary memory address that happens to contain something.

> On the other hand defining a variable means telling the compiler its value.

*Assigning* to a variable means overwriting that chunk of memory with a new value.

> Declaration - Name + Type (of an identifier)
>
> Declaration - Value (of an identifier)

Declaration: Name and Type (and, hence, Size)

Assignment: Value (and, hence, Size)

The size issue doesn't matter for int's, because they're all [conveniently] the same size (although what size depends on your platform); the same *cannot* be said of arrays or "strings" (which are character arrays).